# Smoothness of a morphism of smooth varieties with smooth fibres

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am asking for a *reference* for the following lemma (for which I know a proof).

> **Lemma.** Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a surjective morphism of irreducible *smooth*  complex algebraic varieties (separated, reduced, irreducible schemes of finite type over $\Bbb C$) with *smooth*  fibres over closed points of $Y$. The $f$ is smooth if and only if all these fibres  have the same dimension $\dim X-\dim Y$.

Comment: If $f$ is smooth, then $f$ is flat and the fibres are automatically smooth and equidimensional, see [Vakil, thm. 25.2.2].  This provides one implication of your desired statement. The converse implication is [Vakil, Exercise 25.2.F (a)].

Comment: Another reference: Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory, Theorem 23.1.

Comment: Thank you, @FrancescoPolizzi! I did know the book of Matsumura, but not the text of Ravi Vakil....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me expand my comment into an answer, so that the question will not appear as unanswered anymore.

If $f$ is smooth, then $f$ is flat and its fibres are automatically smooth and equidimensional, see [Vakil, Theorem. 25.2.2]. This provides one implication of your statement. The converse implication is [Vakil, Exercise 25.2.F (a)].

**References.**

[Vakil] R. Vakil, *The Rising Sea: Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*, November 18, 2017 [version](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/).